# Don't automatically build container on docker-compose up

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-remote

Is there a way in VSCode with docker extension to change `docker-compose up` arguments? By default it is started as `docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build`. But I don't want to rebuild project each time. I want to run separate `docker-compose build` command if I need it.
I've looked over [devcontainer.json parameters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference) and [working with containers article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers), but did not find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
This can be done edditing Docker extension settings.
There is a check "Docker: Docker Compose build", which can be removed in order to disable build.
Also, `settings.json` can be changed with `"docker.dockerComposeBuild": false` parameter

Comment: Docker won't build the image again If you didn't change any file relate to the image.